# How to call derived class method in private inheritance?

Tags: c++

Below code is not compiling for me...

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base(){}
    virtual void Display()
    {
        cout << "Base Display" << endl;
    }
};

class Derived : private Base
{
private:
    void Display() override
    {
        cout << "Derived Display" << endl;
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Derived d;
    d.Display();
    Derived* dp = new Derived();
    dp->Display();

    delete dp;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler reporting errors when I am calling `Derived::Display()`. How to call it?
What kind of problems we can solve by writing code like this?

Comment: How much efforts it requires to post the error message as well?

Comment: @Nawaz In this case, the error message isn't required as it is quite obvious with his code (at least the code that is valid syntax).

Comment: The question (maybe accidentally) is more interesting than what many are seeing... don't quite understand the 4 downvotes :) +1 to compensate.

Comment: This one deserves a lot of down votes for not reading error messages!

Comment: @DieterLücking:  Agreed.  Listen to what the compiler tells you.

Comment: @ZacHowland: The reason I asked for error *messages* is because often people don't read and try to understand the error messages (they're *messages* after all, aren't they?) and instead post a question at Stackoverflow. That is bad.

Comment: @Nawaz:  Fair point.  In this case, the error message he would have received would not have made much sense to a novice without a good understanding of the different inheritance models.

Comment: I am experimenting something with private inheritance and didn't recognize the private access specified in the derived class. I thought I kept public there. Yes. This deserves down votes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't access a **private** method from outside the class. Hence the compilation error.

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing two different concepts here, the access specifier of the member function and the access specifier of the base class.

You cannot call the member function because its access specifier is `private` and you are attempting to call from a function that is not a friend. That is regardless of the type of inheritance from `Base` or even if that relationship exists.

The access specifier in the inheritance relationship determines what parts of the code can consider your type to be a `Base` and which cannot. In this particular case, inside `Derived` and its friends you can use a reference or pointer to `Derived` as if it was a `Base`, but not outside of it.

> How to call it? What kind of problems we can solve by writing code like this?

Private inheritance models implemented in terms of, and can be used to provide some functionality through the use of a third party library/class hierarchy from which your own type need not conceptually derive. Avoiding the public inheritance inhibits your users from seeing you as the base, which is intentional as that is a *detail* of implementation. Inside your own type, you can use the inheritance relationship:

```
void detail(Base *base) {
    base->Display();       // Base::Display is public
}
void Derived::show() {     // Derived::show is public:
    detail(this);          // Private inheritance is visible inside Derived
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You've made `Display` private in the derived class, so it's accessible via a pointer/reference to `Base,` but not directly in a `Derived` object, nor via a reference/pointer to `Derived`.

```
// This should work:
Base *b = new Derived;
b->Display();

// and so should this:
Derived d;
Base &b = d;
b.Display();
```

...but either of these would also require public inheritance to allow implicit conversion from `Derived` to `Base`.

Comment: Inheritance is also private, that code would have to be inside a member of `Derived` or a friend of it to compile (`Derived` cannot be bound to a pointer/reference to `Base` outside of `Derived` & friends)

Answer (score 1):

You can't call a derived class method with private inheritance out side of class it become private even if it's defined as public.

Answer (score 0):

Private inheritance hides every method and attribute from outer world, thus your `Derived` instances on heap or stack cannot call Display directly like you did in your main function. You can replace `private` with `public` to avoid these kind of errors or use a pointer to `Base` to access hidden base methods.

Edit: Improved with suggestion by Jerry.

Answer (score 0):

Private inheritance creates a "contains-a" relationship (it is effectively like creating a member variable of the type `Base`).  What you are attempting to do is create an "is-a" relationship, which is done through public inheritance.